# illegal to access static member while in an enum constructor

Tags: java

I have an enum and want to attach a static function to it that takes an argument of that enum's case and returns a different string dependent on some conditions. This is throwing a bunch of errors, though, including "No modifiers allowed for enum constants" and "it is illegal to access static member ... from enum constructor or instance initializer." How do I correctly attach a static function to an enum? Because of my context, this really does seem like the most sensible place to put it.

Example Code:

```
public enum Operation {
    SUM,
    SUBTRACT,
    PRODUCT,
    DIVIDE,


    public String display(Operation operation) {
        if (operation == this.SUM) {
            return "+";
        } else if (operation == this.SUBTRACT) {
            return "-";
        } else if (operation == this.DIVIDE) {
            return "/";
        } else {
            return "*";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What to you mean by "attach a static function to an enum"? How do you imagine such method should work? For now it looks like you just want to assign to each enum value some symbol, like `+` for `SUM`. You can do it by telling enum to have `private String symbol;`, create constructor via which you will set that symbol for each enum value so something like `private Operation(String symbol){ this.symbol = symbol;}` and create values like `SUM("+")`. Create also getter for that symbol like `getSymbol(){ return symbol;}`. This way you can call `SUM.getSymbol()` and get `"+"`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like your main problem:

```
public enum Operation {
    SUM,
    SUBTRACT,
    PRODUCT,
    DIVIDE,
```

That last comma should be a semicolon, to terminate the list of enum member constants.

You might have other issues (I didn't check), but start by fixing that syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should choose a different way to implement what you want to achieve:

```
public enum Operation {
    SUM("+"),
    SUBTRACT("-"),
    PRODUCT("*"),
    DIVIDE("/");

    private final String displayString;

    Operation(final String displayString) {
        this.displayString = displayString;
    }

    public String getDisplayString() {
        return displayString;
    }
}
```

Few key points:

1. Enums in Java can have fields and constructor, see `displayString` field and the one argument constructor.
2. Enums in Java can have instance methods, in which you can use instance fields, like `getDisplayString`

Then you can use it as follows:

```
final Operation sumOperation = Operation.SUM;
final Operation divideOperation = Operation.DIVIDE;

System.out.println("First operation: " + sumOperation.getDisplayString()); // First operation: +
System.out.println("Second operation: " +  divideOperation.getDisplayString()); // Second operation: /
```

I hope it helps, if you need further details please describe what more information you need in the comments